# Error in building qtsampleplayer

Tags: qt, mpeg-dash

I am getting the following error in building qtsampleplayer:

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Libdash/libdash/libdash/qtsampleplayer/build$ make
 [  3%] Automoc for target qtsampleplayer
 [  3%] Built target qtsampleplayer_automoc
 Linking CXX executable qtsampleplayer
 i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.2.1:undefined reference to symbol 'inflateInit2_'
 /libz.so.1:error adding symbols:DSO missing from command line
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[2]: *** [qtsampleplayer] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/qtsampleplayer.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Tried several options like giving path of libz.so in command line but no help

Regards
Mayank

Comment: with gcc linked libraries must be put in the command line after libraries that use it. Try to put the libz linking command in your makefile (or cmake, if I see well) in the last position in the linking command.

Answer (score 0):

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` that means basically that something before went wrong.

`/libz.so.1:error adding symbols:DSO missing from command line`that means that he is not finding DSO so you have not included correctly the libz.so BUT before it says: `i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5.2.1:undefined reference to symbol 'inflateInit2_'` So your problem is not in libz.so, it can be in libQt5Gui .

Do you really have both libraries where your project is looking? Seems the program is not finding them